# Make specific elements readable by screen readers only

Tags: html, css, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm working on UI accessibility, and want to add a specific text to an element, which is then will be read by screen reader software. For example, for every `<li>` item I want to add a message "Switch through the elements using arrow keys". Is there a way of adding such a message? Overriding `aria-label` is, unfortunately, not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is likely to use a [visually hidden class](https://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content/) in CSS, a "hack" that means the text isn't rendered visually, but still announced by screen readers. For example

```
<li>My text my text <span class="visually-hidden">Switch through the elements using arrow keys</span></li>
```

Unfortunately you would have to repeat the same text element at the end of every `<li>`, this cannot be repeated automatically (using CSS `::after` and `content:` has very uneven support between different screen reader vendors).

**However**, although I don't know the wider context, think twice over whether you need to add this info there.

- Do you have custom interactive elements in these `<li>`? In that case, could they not be represented using a different ARIA role, rather than being announced as a list?
- Are you just instructing users how to go to the line below? They probably do not need that: people who use a screen reader user day-to-day know the basics of how it works, and they will know how to navigate a list. Adding that everywhere might frustrate them. Also remember that most different screen readers already give instructions.
- If not: do you have some kind of custom interaction where you capture the down arrow keyup event in Javascript? This will not always work nicely with screen readers, be sure to test it and provide alternative.
- In the rare cases where you do need to add SR-only recommendations, be wary of using language like "use the arrow keys". This won't necessarily make sense if they are on a mobile or tablet, or if they use a braille keyboard, or even depending on their key mapping and screen reader (VoiceOver on Mac, for example, will not move to the next line with the down arrow unless QuickNav is on).

Comment: Thank you, seems like an option. Regarding if this is a good idea - I'm working with screen reader users directly and seems like even experienced users are a bit confused with the way UI tabs are working. They tend to press tab instead of using arrow keys, moving the focus to another element group, which they assume is another tab.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; do you mean that these list items represent UI tabs? In that case then they should be marked up and announced as tabs, and should be focusable with the tab key indeed. Otherwise they will also cause issue for sighted keyboard users. The [ARIA authoring practices have a great section](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#tabpanel) with examples for tabbed interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

WebAIM has a [guide on this](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) and recommends using absolute positioning. Likewise there is another [useful guide](https://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content/) worth reading from TheA11yproject

I encourage you to read about it in full but for convenience and reference here is the CSS from the second example (thank you for the suggestion Victor):

```
.screen-reader-only 
{
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
```

And then you would add the class for text that you want to be, well, for screen readers only. E.g.

```
<div class="screen-reader-only"><a href="#main">Skip to main content</a></div>
```

Naturally you can call the class `hidden` or `visually-hidden` or whatever else makes most sense to you.

**A note of caution**

I would make sure to use this technique sparingly and with consideration of the user experience while navigating.

For example, it should be possible to achieve your `li` example easily enough by applying it to a span inside the `li` element.

```
  <li><span class="screen-reader-only">.... </span>...</li>
```

However I would strongly question whether this is really necessary. Presumably a user of screen reader software is already familiar with how to use it, and has their own way of navigating.

What *can* sometimes be a problem for screen reader users is how cluttered and verbose the semantics of a page are (it's not as easy to skim quickly and holistically as opposed to using visuals). Adding such extra notices could simply contribute to this problem.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!

Comment: Just a quick note about the CSS class you are giving: the negative position technique used by WebAIM is considered deprecated because the browser will still render it off-screen, which may have an impact on performance, and may sometimes be rendered on pages written right-to-left. You should use [CSS clip instead](https://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content/) to be sure.

Comment: Thanks @Victor that's a good point. I have updated my example to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

`title="Switch through the elements using arrow keys"` maybe?